# Giving tolltip to Drop Downlist box when it is populated

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to give tooltip to dropdownlist box as like...

When I just click on the DropDownListBox then it populates the list of items.
When I move on the on of item then color of that item changes to blue I want to assign 
the tooltip for this particular item.

Because my text of listitem is too large which is greater than width of listbox.

Is there any event to capture the moved listitem?

Please tell me how this can be possible.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can loop through the dropdown list items and add a title attribute to each ListItem (if you are using asp.net webforms):

```
    For Each listItem As ListItem In DropDownList.Items
        listItem.Attributes.Add("title", listItem.Text)
    Next
```